# Uploading pdf to sql-alchemy in python using blob

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, blob

I am trying to upload books to sqlite3 in the form of a pdf. I wrote this code that uploads :

- author
- title
- pdf of the story but the blob portion does not seem to work here:

```py
class Book(UserMixin, db.Model):

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        author = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False)
        title = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False)
        pdf= db.Column(db.Blob(10000000))
    
    @app.route('/uploadStory', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def uploadStory():
        new_book = Book(author=form.author.data, title=form.title.data, pdf=form.pdf.data)
        db.session.add(new_book)
        db.session.commit()
```

How do I ensure the user is able to upload the book via PDF? Ideally

- I want the users to upload entire stories
- I want the blob size to be very large
- I do not want to store the stories locally then use the path
- I want to store them using blob

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this using SQLAlchemy, but here's the vanilla Python/Flask way:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

def insert_user_data(author, title, pdf):
    con = sqlite3.connect("user_data.sqlite")
    cur = con.cursor()
    query = """
        INSERT INTO user_data (author, title, pdf) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
    """
    cur.execute(query, [author, title, pdf])
    con.commit()


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        pdf = request.files["pdf"].read()
        author = request.form["author"]
        title = request.form["title"]
        insert_user_data(author, title, pdf)
        return redirect(url_for("home"))

    return render_template("index.html")
```

That assumes this DB schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_data (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    author TEXT,
    title TEXT,
    pdf BLOB
);
```

And a simple `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Save PDF</title>
    <style>
        input {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('home') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="author" />
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="title" />
        <input type="file" name="pdf" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run that, and then run another script to pull the `pdf` from the DB and write to a file (to see if it worked), everything looks good:

```py
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("user_data.sqlite")
cur = con.cursor()

query = """
    SELECT pdf FROM user_data WHERE id = 1;
"""

result = cur.execute(query).fetchone()[0]

with open("think-python.pdf", mode="wb") as file:
    file.write(result)
```

Here's the resulting file structure:

```sh
➜  blob-pdf ls
app.py  main.py  __pycache__  schema.sql  templates  think-python.pdf  user  user_data.sqlite
➜  blob-pdf file think-python.pdf
think-python.pdf: PDF document, version 1.5
```

And here's the file after pulling from the DB:

[image: Think Python]